# PHP pass ups shipping calculated cost to paypal

Tags: php, paypal, ups

I got PayPal payment API working when the user enters his name, address, quantity, etc.

Using the address the user entered into the input tags, how can I use UPS shipping calculator to insert the calculated cost into

```
<input type="hidden" value="UPS COST HERE" name="itemshipping">
```

so that when the user clicks checkout, they already see the total price including the calculated shipping?

I look at the UPS instructions but it seems more complicated than it should be.

Comment: <input type="hidden" value="<?=$variable_that_contains_ups_shipping_cost_goes_here;?>" name="itemshipping">

Comment: My question is how do I get that variable

Comment: You said you saw the "UPS Instructions" show me where you saw these instructions and I will attempt to decipher it for you.

Comment: https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit?loc=en_US, I got the access key, I found some code on google that seemed to be it but I am not sure what to do. If you can point me to a good tutorial that would be much appreciated!